How to create a virtual file in clipboard for pasting into Explorer?
I'm currently developing a wxWidgets application for Windows 10/11 that is supposed to generate a file. This file is security sensitive so minimizing the copies on disk is ideal. As a result, I want to generate this file virtually in memory and copy it to the clipboard for the user to paste it through Microsoft Remote Desktop Connection. I have read Microsoft's documentation on clipboard formats and attempted to implement this using wxWidget's wxDataFormat, wxDataObjectSimple, and wxDataObjectComposite.
Microsoft's documentation leads me to believe that I need to create two data objects with the type CFSTR_FILECONTENTS and CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR to hold the virtual file in memory. From viewing the source of wxWidget's MSW implementation, it appears that wxDataObjectSimple allocates a GlobalAlloc buffer and stores this buffer in a STGMEDIUM structure which is expected for these two formats. As a result, I created a VirtualFileContents and VirtualFileDescriptor class derived from wxDataObjectSimple which provide the file contents and FILEGROUPDESCRIPTOR structure data respectively. A VirtualFile class derives from wxDataObjectComposite to append these two types together.
When implemented this way, I was able to observe in multiple Win32 clipboard viewers that I had the correct clipboard data as described by Microsoft, with both the "FileContents" and "FileGroupDescriptor" as both "HGlobal" handle types with the expected data and correct format within. When opening a context menu in Explorer, the option to paste is available however a spinning cursor appears for a few frames and then the system bell rings to indicate an error. No error dialog is displayed, and no file is pasted.
To further debug this situation, I opened up a copy of Microsoft Outlook 2016 and copied an attachment from an email. This is also implemented in a similar way with CFSTR_FILECONTENTS and CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTOR but Outlook's file contains are an "IStream" type and not an "HGlobal" type. This pasted into Explorer just fine, and I compared the layout of the FileGroupDescriptor structure and saw no memory layout errors. I saw that Outlook includes both a FileGroupDescriptorW and a FileGroupDescriptor when copying files, but implementing that myself has not resolved the issue either. Below is a snippet of my current implementation:
Header
namespace Clipboard {


class VirtualFileContents : public wxDataObjectSimple {
  private:
    std::string m_str;
 
  public:
    VirtualFileContents(const std::string &str);
 
    std::size_t GetDataSize() const;
    bool GetDataHere(void *buf) const;
};
 
class VirtualFileDescriptorW : public wxDataObjectSimple {
  private:
    std::wstring m_fileName;
    VirtualFileContents &m_contents;
 
  public:
    VirtualFileDescriptorW(const std::wstring &file_name, VirtualFileContents &contents);
 
    std::size_t GetDataSize() const;
    bool GetDataHere(void *buf) const;
};
 
class VirtualFileDescriptorA : public wxDataObjectSimple {
  private:
    std::string m_fileName;
    VirtualFileContents &m_contents;
 
  public:
    VirtualFileDescriptorA(const std::string &file_name, VirtualFileContents &contents);
 
    std::size_t GetDataSize() const;
    bool GetDataHere(void *buf) const;
};
 
class VirtualFile : public wxDataObjectComposite {
  private:
    VirtualFileContents *m_contents;
    VirtualFileDescriptorW *m_wDescriptor;
    VirtualFileDescriptorA *m_aDescriptor;
 
  public:
    VirtualFile(const std::string &str, const std::filesystem::path &file_name);
};
 
};  // namespace Clipboard

Source
Clipboard::VirtualFileContents::VirtualFileContents(const std::string &str)
    : wxDataObjectSimple{CFSTR_FILECONTENTS}, m_str(str) {
}
 
std::size_t Clipboard::VirtualFileContents::GetDataSize() const {
    return this->m_str.size();
}
 
bool Clipboard::VirtualFileContents::GetDataHere(void *buf) const {
    std::memcpy(buf, this->m_str.data(), this->m_str.size());
    return true;
}
 
Clipboard::VirtualFileDescriptorW::VirtualFileDescriptorW(const std::wstring &file_name,
                                                          VirtualFileContents &contents)
    : wxDataObjectSimple{CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORW}, m_fileName(file_name), m_contents(contents) {
}
 
std::size_t Clipboard::VirtualFileDescriptorW::GetDataSize() const {
    return sizeof(FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW);
}
 
bool Clipboard::VirtualFileDescriptorW::GetDataHere(void *buf) const {
    if (this->m_fileName.size() >= MAX_PATH) {
        std::runtime_error("File name too long.");
    }
 
    FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORW files = {
        .cItems = 1,
        .fgd = {{.dwFlags = 0,
                 .clsid = {},
                 .sizel = {},
                 .pointl = {},
                 .dwFileAttributes = 0x0,
                 .ftCreationTime = {},
                 .ftLastAccessTime = {},
                 .ftLastWriteTime = {},
                 .nFileSizeHigh = 0, //static_cast<DWORD>(this->m_contents.GetDataSize() >> 32),
                 .nFileSizeLow = 0, //static_cast<DWORD>(this->m_contents.GetDataSize() & 0xFFFFFFFF),
                 .cFileName = L""}}};
    std::memcpy(files.fgd[0].cFileName, this->m_fileName.data(),
                this->m_fileName.size() * sizeof(decltype(this->m_fileName)::value_type));
 
    std::memcpy(buf, &files, sizeof(files));
    return true;
}
 
Clipboard::VirtualFileDescriptorA::VirtualFileDescriptorA(const std::string &file_name,
                                                          VirtualFileContents &contents)
    : wxDataObjectSimple{CFSTR_FILEDESCRIPTORA}, m_fileName(file_name), m_contents(contents) {
}
 
std::size_t Clipboard::VirtualFileDescriptorA::GetDataSize() const {
    return sizeof(FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORA);
}
 
bool Clipboard::VirtualFileDescriptorA::GetDataHere(void *buf) const {
    if (this->m_fileName.size() >= MAX_PATH) {
        std::runtime_error("File name too long.");
    }
 
    FILEGROUPDESCRIPTORA files = {
        .cItems = 1,
        .fgd = {{.dwFlags = 0,
                 .clsid = {},
                 .sizel = {},
                 .pointl = {},
                 .dwFileAttributes = 0x0,
                 .ftCreationTime = {},
                 .ftLastAccessTime = {},
                 .ftLastWriteTime = {},
                 .nFileSizeHigh = 0,
                 .nFileSizeLow = 0,
                 .cFileName = ""}}};
    std::memcpy(files.fgd[0].cFileName, this->m_fileName.data(),
                this->m_fileName.size() * sizeof(decltype(this->m_fileName)::value_type));
 
    std::memcpy(buf, &files, sizeof(files));
    return true;
}
 
Clipboard::VirtualFile::VirtualFile(const std::string &str, const std::filesystem::path &file_name)
    : m_contents(new VirtualFileContents{str}),
      m_wDescriptor(new VirtualFileDescriptorW{file_name.wstring(), *this->m_contents}),
      m_aDescriptor(new VirtualFileDescriptorA{file_name.string(), *this->m_contents}) {
    this->Add(this->m_wDescriptor, true);
    this->Add(this->m_aDescriptor);
    this->Add(this->m_contents);
}

Copy code
if (wxTheClipboard->Open()) {
    wxTheClipboard->SetData(new Clipboard::VirtualFile("hello there", "test.txt"));
    wxTheClipboard->Close();
}

Is anyone aware of any flaw in my approach, or any tools that might help me debug Windows clipboard/Explorer compatibility more? Is it a more simple issue like me just excluding creation time in the structure?

Please build the debug version of the library and your application and see if there is an assertion of some kind. By your explanation it seems you are working with the Release version of both.

@Igor Everything is built on the CMake Debug build type.

what compiler did you use? Please try to step thru the code and see what portion fails to perform. If you are running Debug build you have a source code of the library - use it.

@Igor The code itself does not fail to run or perform its expected function. It sets the global Windows clipboard state as anticipated. The issue is: why does this data format not get accepted into Windows Explorer?

a spinning cursor appears for a few frames and then the system bell rings to indicate an error. No error dialog is displayed, and no file is pasted., this is an indication of an error. What happen (what is in the clipboard) if you do copy/paste on the regular file from explorer to explorer?

@Igor Pasting a regular file in Explorer works as expected, and the clipboard contains a CF_HDROP object with the file path alongside a FileGroupDescriptorW describing the file name and attributes. This behavior is also expected from the MS documentation. I included the Outlook example in my question because it demonstrates the exact behavior I am trying to recreate, and the paste from Outlook works.

Hello, I'm not familiar with wxWidgets, but I do know how to put virtual files into the clipboard. I've worked on the clipboard sharing feature (for remote desktop) before, and in that process, I would use IDataObject and IStream in the Windows API. If you want to put virtual files into the clipboard and make it compatible with any software that needs to perform pasting, this should be achievable 100%.

I believe this is impossible to implement through wxWidgets due to a limitation in the MSW port which prevents settings the lindex value of the FORMATETC structure which is mandatory for the virtual file to be recognized.
I have created a feature request here to try and discuss how to solve this issue moving forward.
